# Xamarin ToolBarItem click event not redirecting page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin ToolBarItem click event not redirecting page

Here is MyCode

.xamal

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Command="{Binding HomeMenuCommand}" Order="Primary" Icon="tab_home.png.png" Text="Home" Priority="0" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

ViewModel

```
public ICommand HomeMenuCommand { get; }

public AboutViewModel()
{
   Title = "About";
   HomeMenuCommand = new Command(async () => await GoToHomeCommand());
}

async Task GoToHomeCommand()
{
   await this.PushPageFromCacheAsync<MainViewModel>();
}
```

This Page is on TopOf Tabbed Page and I am using [Xamvvm](https://github.com/xamvvm/xamvvm) to view model binding

when I put

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("test...", "test", "OK");
```

inside of GoToHomeCommand() message, Alert generates

Please help me to solve

Comment: try `bool success = await PushPageFromCacheAsync<MainViewModel>();` Any error codes or something ?

Comment: NO any error codes...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that Xamvvm though, but looking at your problem, it seems your command is working properly. The only problem is the redirecting.

Have you tried this one?

```
async Application.MainPage.Current = new NavigationPage(new YourPage());
```

Comment: sry this also same issue